# CDC in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, change-data-capture

i have enabled CDC feature on one of my database.  now i have below table data in cdc tables

```
MemberID            LastName      __$operation
1                   David         4   
1                   Dave          4
2                   Jimmy         4
2                   Test          4
```

Now my problem is that i have to query the cdc table and get all the rows that are the latest one for all the members (most recent updated value). for example the query would return

```
MemberID            LastName      __$operation
1                   Dave          4
2                   Test          4
```

Comment: There is no field in this table to tell you what the latest record is, so this is impossible. Unless you have more fields you're not telling us about.

Comment: Point is in SQL Server tables are sets with no default ordering of data. So you will have to alter your table to add a column (ex: datetime) based on which asc/desc ordering can be defined on the rows.Then you can use row_number rank function or correlated sub queries to get latest records.

Comment: So do you need to see the latest values only for rows that have changed or the latest values for all rows whether they have changed or not?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the _*$operation column, there are also the _*$start_lsn and __$seq_val columns. Ordering by those two should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

You can not only determine by _$operations for CDC. If you want to do it correct use other column fields that are:

```
__$start_lsn
__$end_lsn
__$seqval
__$update_mask
```

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are asking for, but if you need the latest values for all the members in the table then ignore the CDC table and just query the table itself as this is where all the latest values are afterall.

If you need to see the latest values for all the members that have been changed within a certain time period, then you should use the cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_(capture_instance) function, detailed here:

[cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522511%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

This allows you to specify a start and end date for the capture period (via the sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn function which allows you to map the LSNs to actual times) and it will then output the net changes to the table within this period.

The cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_(capture_instance) changes is generated depending on your table name, so as you have not specified what this is, I have called it dbo_members, please change as required, here is an example of how you can get a list of the latest values for all changed members within the last day using the functions detailed above:

```
DECLARE @begin_time DATETIME ,
    @end_time DATETIME ,
    @begin_lsn BINARY(10) ,
    @end_lsn BINARY(10);
SELECT  @begin_time = GETDATE() - 1 ,
        @end_time = GETDATE(); 
SELECT  @begin_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than',
                                                @begin_time); 
SELECT  @end_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal',
                                              @end_time); 
SELECT  [MemberID] ,
        [LastName]
FROM    cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_members(@begin_lsn, @end_lsn, 'all') 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

As per steoleary you can simply check the data table for the latest values and ignore CDC altogether, but if you are looking to what changed with values from and to, then you will need to refer to the _$operation values 3 (deleted) and 4 (inserted) values in conjunction with the __$start_lsn. The inserted and deleted values correspond to those tables you would use when writing triggers btw.

To just see what column values changes as a precursor to actually evaluating those values, then you can use the __$update_mask column, tied into the cdc.captured_columns table which will provide you the actual column names, by implementing the sys.fn_cdc_is_bit_set(captured_columns.column_ordinal, __$update_mask) function where the result = 1.

Welcome to the wacky world of CDC and the copious amounts of late nights and caffeine hits required to even attempt to master it!

Answer (score 0):

If your cdc system table name is `cdc.dbo_demo_ct` then with following query you will get desired result:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER (partition BY a.MemberID ORDER BY b.tran_end_time DESC) t,
                       *
FROM   cdc.dbo_demo_ct a
  INNER JOIN cdc.lsn_time_mapping b
ON a.__$start_lsn = b.start_lsn) T
WHERE  T.t = 1
```